# How to build libav using ndk-build in cygwin for windowds?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to know how to build **libav** on windows7 using **cygwin**. I've tried the following steps :

1-change the directory using cd command to  libav_file_directory/android(android folder is empty where the .so file will be saved as far as my knowledge is concern).

2-execute the ./ndk-buil command.

I got the following as result:

*Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.
/cygdrive/c/Users/balwant.singh.TA/Desktop/Android/android-ndk-r8/build/core/build-local.mk:130: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.*

plese reply with solution, **and also I want to know which all android media player uses the libav as their native code.**

Answer (score 1):

1.)Set all your paths(Java_Home

2.)Set NDK_HOME to Ndk-Build Path

3.)Run Cygwin

4.)GO to project Library path

5.)Run **make** command

6.)then Run **ndk-build**